# Upper bound for largest eigenvalue of matrix product involving Hadamard product and projections

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times k}$ and $B\in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$ with $n$ larger than both $m$ and $k$ and with both matrices of full column rank. Let $P$ denote the projection matrix onto the column space of $A$, that is, $P = A (A^T A)^{-1} A^T$. It is clear that $(I-P) A = 0$.

Consider the problem of finding an upper bound for the largest eigenvalue of
$$
C = (I-P) (A A^T \circ B B^T) (I-P),
$$
where $\circ$ denotes the Hadamard product (that we take to have lower priority than ordinary matrix multiplication, such that $A \circ BC$ means $A \circ (BC)$). In particular, I'm looking for bounds that involve the largest eigenvalue of $A A^T$ and possibly $(I-P)B$.

EDIT:

The largest eigenvalue of $C$ is clearly upper bounded by the largest eigenvalue of $(A A^T \circ B B^T) (I-P)$ since $I-P$ is a projection and thus has eigenvalues only equal to $0$ or $1$.

The largest eigenvalue of $(A A^T \circ B B^T) (I-P)$ is upper bounded by the trace which commutes with the Hadamard product (by 2.6 [here](http://buzzard.ups.edu/courses/2007spring/projects/million-paper.pdf)) thus
$$
\lambda_{\max}((A A^T \circ B B^T) (I-P)) \leq \mathrm{tr}((A A^T \circ B B^T) (I-P))= \mathrm{tr}(\{(I-P) \circ B B^T\} A A^T).
$$
The trace is upper bounded by the largest eigenvalue $AA^T$ times $\mathrm{tr}(\{(I-P) \circ B B^T\})$(see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3103958/inequality-for-trace-of-product-of-matrices)) thus (using that $I-P$ is a projection)
$$
\mathrm{tr}(\{(I-P) \circ B B^T\} A A^T) \leq \lambda_{\max}(AA^T) \mathrm{tr}((I-P)(I-P)^T \circ BB^T).
$$
It remains to upper bound $\mathrm{tr}((I-P)(I-P)^T \circ BB^T)$ through $(I-P)B$ somehow. Utilising the "transposed Khatri-Rao product" $\odot$ (sometimes called the [facesplitting product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khatri%E2%80%93Rao_product#Face-splitting_product)), we can write
$$
\mathrm{tr}((I-P)(I-P)^T \circ BB^T) = \mathrm{tr}(\{(I-P) \odot B\}\{(I-P) \odot B\}^T) = \| (I-P) \odot B \|_F^2.
$$
Numerical evidence shows that this is of roughly the same size as the  nuclear norm of $(I-P)B$ at least when $m$ is larger than $1$.

NEW EDIT:
I have numerically verified that
$$
\mathrm{tr}((I-P)(I-P)^T \circ BB^T) = \|[(I-P) \circ (I-P)] [B \circ B] \|_1,
$$
where $\| A \|_1 := \| \mathrm{Vec}(A) \|_1$ denotes the entrywise L1 norm. In fact it seems (numerically at least) that a very crude bound of the largest eigenvalue of $C$ is $\lambda_{\max}(AA^T) \| (I-P)B \|_1^2$.

Comment: It is unlikely that you will find such an expression. There is no general result for the eigenvalues for the Hadamard product of two matrices.

Comment: @KBS note that I am not looking for an equality but merely an upper bound. There are known results on upper bounds of eigenvalues of Hadamard products.

Comment: Even that. The eigenvalues of $AA^T\circ BB^T$ are difficult to evaluate. They have no relationship with the eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$, in general. The only thing we know is that this term is positive semidefinite. I guess you will have to approach your problem differently.

Comment: @KSB But I do not require a bound in terms of eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$ (they are not square so this does not even make sense). We know that the largest eigenvalue of $A A^T \circ B B^T$ is upper bounded by the product of the largest eigenvalue of $A A^T$ and $B B^T$, so I don't really understand what you mean. 

I do agree that it is not obvious how (or if it is even possible) to produce the bound I desire.

Comment: I meant $AA^T$ and $BB^T$. Without more assumptions/conditions on the matrices, it will not be possible to find such a bound.

Comment: @KSB I'm confused, do you not agree that an easy upper bound is the product of the largest eigenvalues of $AA^T$ and the largest eigenvalue of $B B^T$? So certainly something can be done?

Comment: Do you have a reference for that statement? Moreover, you cannot conclude on anything just based on the knowledge of the largest eigenvalue. Just pick $C^TDC$ where $C=\mathrm{diag}(1/2,2)$ and $D=\mathrm{diag}(2,1)$. The largest eigenvalue of $D$ is 2, yet the largest eigenvalue of $C^TDC$ is 4 and does not depend on the maximum eigenvalue of $D$.

Comment: Ok, in fact, if we use the properties of the matrix $P$, then a rough bound on the eigenvalues of $C$ is given by the product of the largest eigenvalue of $AA^T$ and $BB^T$. It will be difficult to do better than that, I guess.

Comment: @KBS I'm not as pessimistic as you are, I've added some more of my thoughts to the post.

Comment: Please provide some details about your calculations with appropriate references to the results you are using. Otherwise, no one will be really able to you if you only give partial information. But you can already simplify $(I-P)(I-P)^T$ as $I-P$. You also need to mention that the standard matrix product applies before the Hadamard product to make sure that people understand what you wrote.

Comment: @KBS Apologies for the lack of clarity, I will add some more details!

Comment: The largest eigenvalue of $C$ is in fact equal to the largest eigenvalue of $(A A^T \circ B B^T) (I-P)$. So, that improves things a little bit. This follows from the fact the for square matrices $Q,R$, the eigenvalue of $QR$ are the same as $RQ$ and that $(I-P)^2=(I-P)$ together with $(I-P)^T=I-P$.

Comment: @KBS Thank you for this, that makes sense!